Match the raster values from a dbf table and filter based on raster
I have a large raster covering Australia which I applied crop() and mask() to using a multi polygon sf (nested catchments). I read the dbf table using the foreign package, terra::rast() for the tif. I then ensured each file has the same CRS.
When I tried to match the dbf with cells in my raster, it doesn't give me what I expect because my raster doesn't have value. It just contain "forest categorize (native and non forest). I need to link data from the dbf table with my raster so I can filter cells.
For example, I want to select just the cells which are "Native forest" from  the Forest_CATEGO column, and the "HT_CODE" and "COVER_CODE" columns %in% c(1,2,3). I then want to filter only those catchments which contain more than 60% of this condition in their area (here I should consider the catchments are nested). I don't know if this kind of filtering is possible?
This a view of nested catchments.
Here is my code:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78

library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:terra':
#> 
#>     intersect, union
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

install.packages("foreign")
#> Warning: package 'foreign' is in use and will not be installed

# File paths
raster_file <- "C:/Users/for23.tif"
dbf_file <- "C:/Users/for23.tif.vat.dbf"
shapefile <- "C:/Users/boundry.shp"

# Load the raster, .dbf table, and shapefile
rast <- rast(raster_file)
rast
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 38370, 40100, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#> extent      : -1888000, 2122000, -4847000, -1010000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : GDA_1994_Albers 
#> source      : aus_for23.tif 
#> categories  : FOR_CATEGO, FOR_TYPE, FOR_CODE, COVER_CODE, HT_CODE, FOREST, STATE, FOR_SOURCE 
#> name        :    FOR_CATEGO 
#> min value   :    Non-forest 
#> max value   : Native forest

level <- levels(rast)
head(level)
#> [[1]]
#>     VALUE            FOR_CATEGO
#> 1       1            Non-forest
#> 2       2            Non-forest
#> 3       3         Native forest
#> 4       4         Native forest
#> 5       5         Native forest
#> 6       6         Native forest
#> 7       7         Native forest
#> 8       8         Native forest
#> 9       9         Native forest
#> 10     10         Native forest

dbf_table <- read.dbf(dbf_file)
head(dbf_table)
#>   VALUE     COUNT    FOR_CATEGO   FOR_TYPE FOR_CODE COVER_CODE HT_CODE FOREST
#> 1     1 121022073    Non-forest Non-forest        0          6       6      0
#> 2     2      5875    Non-forest Non-forest        0          6       6      0
#> 3     3     17703 Native forest   Mangrove       63          3       2      1
#> 4     4       335 Native forest   Mangrove       61          1       2      1
#> 5     5     16724 Native forest Rainforest       98          3       2      1
#> 6     6      4555 Native forest Rainforest       96          3       1      1
#>   STATE       FOR_SOURCE
#> 1   Qld             <NA>
#> 2  <NA>             <NA>
#> 3   Qld Global Mangroves
#> 4   Qld Global Mangroves
#> 5   Qld         NVIS 6.0
#> 6   Qld         NVIS 6.0


catchments <- vect(shapefile)
shapefile1<- st_read(shapefile)
#> Error in st_read(shapefile): could not find function "st_read"


if (st_crs(shapefile1) != crs(rast)) {
  shapefile_data <- st_transform(shapefile1, st_crs(rast))
}
#> Error in st_crs(shapefile1): could not find function "st_crs"


# Inspect the .dbf table
head(dbf_table)
#>   VALUE     COUNT    FOR_CATEGO   FOR_TYPE FOR_CODE COVER_CODE HT_CODE FOREST
#> 1     1 121022073    Non-forest Non-forest        0          6       6      0
#> 2     2      5875    Non-forest Non-forest        0          6       6      0
#> 3     3     17703 Native forest   Mangrove       63          3       2      1
#> 4     4       335 Native forest   Mangrove       61          1       2      1
#> 5     5     16724 Native forest Rainforest       98          3       2      1
#> 6     6      4555 Native forest Rainforest       96          3       1      1
#>   STATE       FOR_SOURCE
#> 1   Qld             <NA>
#> 2  <NA>             <NA>
#> 3   Qld Global Mangroves
#> 4   Qld Global Mangroves
#> 5   Qld         NVIS 6.0
#> 6   Qld         NVIS 6.0

croped<- crop(rast, vect(shapefile_data))
#> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'vect': object 'shapefile_data' not found

masked_hrs<- mask(rast, vect(shapefile_data))
#> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'mask' in selecting a method for function 'mask': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'vect': object 'shapefile_data' not found

levels(masked_hrs)<- list(dbf_table)
#> Error: object 'masked_hrs' not found

# Define conditions
condition <- dbf_table$FOR_CATEGO == "Native forest" &
  dbf_table$COVER_CODE %in% c(1, 2, 3) &
  dbf_table$HT_CODE %in% c(1, 2, 3)

link to my data

It will be much easier to help you if you provide a minimal, reproducible example. Given the extent of your data, it is likely too large to share using dput() so download links to raster_file, dbf_file, and shapefile will help. It might be possible to help if you add the results of running rast, catchments, and head(dbf_table) to your question as an edit, but access to your actual data would be better. If your data are confidential, you can create some toy data that replicates your issue and add that instead.

I have provide a partial answer that gets as far as assigning the values you need. I tried to access your linked data but it required authentication. If you add links for your data so that authentication is not required, I will update my answer

Your SpatRaster has one layer, but you added multiple levels using list(dbf_table). Based on your description, it is probably better to simply assign levels using a two-column dataframe.
Here is a reprex that assumes:

dbf_table is a summary of every combination of values in your SpatRaster e.g. 10 distinct categories in both your SpatRaster and dbf_table (or however many exist in your actual data)
VALUE in your SpatRaster == VALUE in dbf_table

As head() only returned the first six rows of dbf_table, the solution below will only use the values as shown in your question (n = 6).
First, load required packages and create example data:
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

# Create example dbf file
dbf_table <- structure(list(VALUE = 1:6, COUNT = c(121022073L, 5875L, 17703L, 
335L, 16724L, 4555L), FOR_CATEGO = c("Non-forest", "Non-forest", 
"Native forest", "Native forest", "Native forest", "Native forest"
), FOR_TYPE = c("Non-forest", "Non-forest", "Mangrove", "Mangrove", 
"Rainforest", "Rainforest"), FOR_CODE = c(0L, 0L, 63L, 61L, 98L, 
96L), COVER_CODE = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), HT_CODE = c(6L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), FOREST = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), STATE = c("Qld", 
"<NA>", "Qld", "Qld", "Qld", "Qld"), FOR_SOURCE = c("<NA>", "<NA>", 
"Global Mangroves", "Global Mangroves", "NVIS 6.0", "NVIS 6.0"
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

# Create SpatRaster based on your metadata (lower resolution example)
r <- rast(nrows = 3837, ncols = 4010,
          ext = ext(-1888000, 2122000, -4847000, -1010000),
          crs = "EPSG:3577")

# Assign values to SpatRaster in order to replicate your actual data
set.seed(123)
values(r) <- sample(dbf_table$VALUE,
                    size = ncell(r),
                    replace = TRUE,
                    prob = 1 / sum(dbf_table$COUNT) * dbf_table$COUNT)

# Set the levels for the SpatRaster
levels(r) <- dbf_table[, c("VALUE", "FOR_CATEGO")]

head(levels(r))
# [[1]]
#   VALUE    FOR_CATEGO
# 1     1    Non-forest
# 2     2    Non-forest
# 3     3 Native forest
# 4     4 Native forest
# 5     5 Native forest
# 6     6 Native forest

# Create example mask sf
sf_poly <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -1.5e6,
                               ymin = -3.5e6,
                               xmax = -1.44e6,
                               ymax = -3.44e6))) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 3577)

# Mask and crop r
r1 <- crop(r, vect(sf_poly))
r1 <- mask(r1, vect(sf_poly))

Given that you want to subset your data (based on your defined conditions), it makes sense to convert all other values to NA. If you need to retain all values/levels, skip this next step (note that if you do, the ggplot() examples below may also need to be modified).
# Keep only wanted values, change others to NA
r1[!(r1 %in% dbf_table[dbf_table$FOR_CATEGO == "Native forest" &
                         dbf_table$COVER_CODE %in% 1:3 &
                         dbf_table$HT_CODE %in% 1:3, 1])] <- NA

# Change levels to desired variable e.g. FOR_TYPE
levels(r1) <- dbf_table[, c("VALUE", "FOR_TYPE")]

r1
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 60, 60, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
# extent      : -1500000, -1440000, -3500000, -3440000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : GDA94 / Australian Albers (EPSG:3577) 
# source(s)   : memory
# categories  : FOR_TYPE 
# name        :   FOR_TYPE 
# min value   :   Mangrove 
# max value   : Rainforest 

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r1, maxcell = Inf) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = FALSE,
                    name = "Type") +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


If you need more nuance in your output, you can do do something like:
# Change levels to desired variable e.g. FOR_CODE
levels(r1) <- dbf_table[, c("VALUE", "FOR_CODE")]

r1
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 60, 60, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
# extent      : -1500000, -1440000, -3500000, -3440000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : GDA94 / Australian Albers (EPSG:3577) 
# source(s)   : memory
# categories  : FOR_CODE 
# name        : FOR_CODE 
# min value   :       63 
# max value   :       96 

# For legend (illustrative purposes only)
legend <- subset(dbf_table, dbf_table$VALUE %in% as.numeric(unique(values(r1))))

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r1, maxcell = Inf) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Type/Code",
                    labels = paste(legend$FOR_TYPE, legend$FOR_CODE),
                    values = c("#61D04F" ,"#009292", "darkgreen"),
                    na.translate = FALSE) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())

Note that even though your defined condition returns four rows from the dbf_table used in this example, only three distinct levels were within the extent of sf_polygon:

